# AutoMapper - Can't map two types in same method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, dto

I've been searching around but haven't found this particular problem. I've found threads regarding mapping multiple types to the same entity, but not this... And i don't think this should be a problem.

When I first map an EventDto to an EventUserViewModel, it works. When I later on map an EventDto to an EventViewModel, it crashes because AutoMapper thinks I want to map to an EvenUserViewModel again?

If I change the order, the same problem occurs, only reversed.

Providing some code here; it's basically the stripped down example of where the problem occurs.

```
// Mapping an EventDto to a EventUserViewModel
EventUsersViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<EventUsersViewModel>(eventService.GetEventDto(id));

// Getting a list of EventDtos
var myEvents = eventService.GetMyEvents(User.Identity.GetUserId(), User.IsInRole(RoleNames.ADMIN_USER));

// Mapping all EventDtos to EventViewModels
List<EventViewModel> eventViewModelList = myEvents.Select(Mapper.Map<EventViewModel>).ToList();
```

The last line is where it fails. AutoMapper tries to map my EventDtos to EventUserViewModels instead of EventViewModel even though I'm strictly specifying the types.

Comment: I imagine this is caused by the static api on the Mapper. It was made obsolete early in the year [Removing the static API from AutoMapper](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a new instance of AutoMapper. I'm sure there is a better way of doing this.

Final code:

```
// Mapping an EventDto to a EventUserViewModel
EventUsersViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<EventUsersViewModel>(eventService.GetEventDto(id));

// Getting a list of EventDtos
var myEvents = eventService.GetMyEvents(User.Identity.GetUserId(), User.IsInRole(RoleNames.ADMIN_USER));

// Mapping all EventDtos to EventViewModels
Mapper mapper = Mapper.Configuration.CreateMapper(); 
List<EventViewModel> eventViewModelList = myEvents.Select(mapper.Map<EventViewModel>).ToList();
```